# Transactions in .Net 2.0 application-- what to use?

Tags: sql-server-2008, .net-2.0, transactionscope

I'm working on a .Net 2.0 application and need to wrap some database transactions in my code.  The backend is SQL Server 2008.

I've been away from .net for a few years, the last time I did any transaction processing was in .Net 1.1 with serviced components.  I know about TransactionScope, and was wondering if that's a good way to go about things now.

Also, in .Net 3.5 I assume there are other ways to do this, say with WCF?  Just wondering if someone could point me toward an article or two.  Thanks very much.

Comment: You can run raw SQL queries using `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` and wrapping it around a transaction, but I suggest looking into using an ORM of some sort. Running raw SQL queries is not that great, it runs 'close to the code', but you can't test it easily and one slip-up could mean you royally screw something up.

Comment: I would also consider writing stored procedures to encapsulate the different transactions you need to process.  This will keep transaction scope at the database layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TransactionScope is a good way, provided you keep it in check. All ADO.Net providers are aware of the System.Transactions objects so they will enlist properly into a back end transaction when operating under a TransactionScope.

There are two gotchas:

- Isolation level. .Net framework loves escalating every measly read to a full isolation level transaciton and 99.99% of the times this is overkill. "[By default, the System.Transactions infrastructure creates Serializable transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.isolationlevel.aspx)". Make sure you set it to something more reasonable (Snapshot and Read Commited are good choices).

> . You can determine the
>   isolation level of an existing
>   transaction using the IsolationLevel
>   property of a transaction.

- Distributed transactions. Whithin a transaction scope the moment you use a *second* ADO.Net connection the TransactionScope will enlist it, together with the first one, into a distributed transaciton, even when both transacitons point to the same database. Make sure you use one and only one connection within a transaciton scope.

Technically the last point applies to using *any* resource manager, but is unlikely you'll use any other RM than your db connections. IF you do, then enlisting into a distributed transaction is the proper action anyway.